# Entity Framework Database First Generating Incorrect Model

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-database-first

I have been having issues with Entity Framework the past few days and I posted a question over the weekend that I thought was my problem, but turns out, I believe it is either my model or Entity Framework itself.  So, I first tried to create model classes that best describe how my entities should be defined and then had EF generate the database for me.  For the most part, it got it right, until I added another class that relates back to another and it threw a warning about cascading deletes.  Thanks to @Florian Haider, he instructed me how to tell EF to disable the cascading deletes.  But again, this does not solve my actual issue.  I believe either my model or database is incorrect.

This question is intended to describe the issue I'm having when I create a data model in VS2015 from the database that I think it should be creating in the opposite direction.  So here goes:

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AcademicYear](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [BeginDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EndDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SchoolID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AcademicYear] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AcademicYear] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_AcademicYear_ID]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [ID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AcademicYear] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_AcademicYear_CreateDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [CreateDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AcademicYear]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_AcademicYear_AcademicYear] FOREIGN KEY([SchoolID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[School] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AcademicYear] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_AcademicYear_AcademicYear]
GO
```

And then I have the relating table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[School](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [MissionStatement] [nvarchar](1024) NULL,
    [AddressLine1] [nvarchar](1024) NOT NULL,
    [AddressLine2] [nvarchar](1024) NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [StateCode] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [PostalCode] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [FaxNumber] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [EmailAddress] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [WebsiteURL] [nvarchar](1024) NULL,
    [CurrentAcademicYearID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [EnrollmentAcademicYearID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_School] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[School] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_School_ID]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [ID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[School] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_School_CreateDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [CreateDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[School]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_School_AcademicYear] FOREIGN KEY([CurrentAcademicYearID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AcademicYear] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[School] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_School_AcademicYear]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[School]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_School_AcademicYear1] FOREIGN KEY([EnrollmentAcademicYearID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AcademicYear] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[School] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_School_AcademicYear1]
GO
```

After creating the Entity Data Model in VS2015, the resulting model classes look like the following...

Academic Year:

```
[Table("AcademicYear")]
    public partial class AcademicYear
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public AcademicYear()
        {
            CellGroup = new HashSet<CellGroup>();
            FeeSchedule = new HashSet<FeeSchedule>();
            ParentEnrollment = new HashSet<ParentEnrollment>();
            ReportingPeriod = new HashSet<ReportingPeriod>();
            School1 = new HashSet<School>();
            School2 = new HashSet<School>();
            StudentEnrollment = new HashSet<StudentEnrollment>();
            VolunteerPosition = new HashSet<VolunteerPosition>();
        }

        public Guid ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        public Guid SchoolID { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }

        public bool Active { get; set; }

        public virtual School School { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<CellGroup> CellGroup { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<FeeSchedule> FeeSchedule { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ParentEnrollment> ParentEnrollment { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ReportingPeriod> ReportingPeriod { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<School> School1 { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<School> School2 { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<StudentEnrollment> StudentEnrollment { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<VolunteerPosition> VolunteerPosition { get; set; }
    }
```

School:

```
 [Table("School")]
    public partial class School
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public School()
        {
            AcademicYear = new HashSet<AcademicYear>();
            Parent = new HashSet<Parent>();
            Student = new HashSet<Student>();
        }

        public Guid ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(256)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [StringLength(1024)]
        public string MissionStatement { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(1024)]
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

        [StringLength(1024)]
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(256)]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(256)]
        public string StateCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(256)]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(256)]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [StringLength(256)]
        public string FaxNumber { get; set; }

        [StringLength(256)]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        [StringLength(1024)]
        public string WebsiteURL { get; set; }

        public Guid? CurrentAcademicYearID { get; set; }

        public Guid? EnrollmentAcademicYearID { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }

        public bool Active { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<AcademicYear> AcademicYear { get; set; }

        public virtual AcademicYear AcademicYear1 { get; set; }

        public virtual AcademicYear AcademicYear2 { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Parent> Parent { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Student> Student { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, me personally, I think the model should look like the following...

Academic Year:

```
 [Table("AcademicYear")]
    public class AcademicYear : BaseEntity 
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ReportingPeriod> ReportingPeriods { get; set; }

        //public virtual ICollection<VolunteerPosition> VolunteerPositions { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CellGroup> CellGroups { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ParentEnrollment> ParentEnrollments { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<StudentEnrollment> StudentEnrollments { get; set; }
    }
```

School:

```
 [Table("School")]
    public class School : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string MissionStatement { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string StateCode { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string FaxNumber { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string WebsiteURL { get; set; }

        public Guid? CurrentAcademicYearID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CurrentAcademicYearID")]
        public virtual AcademicYear CurrentAcademicYear { get; set; }

        public Guid? EnrollmentAcademicYearID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("EnrollmentAcademicYearID")]
        public virtual AcademicYear EnrollmentAcademicYear { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Parent> Parents { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
```

Am I wrong?  Is this a problem with my tables or EF (or both)?  Where did the collections of School1 and School2 come from?

Comment: Is this an existing database and you want to setup EF to match it (database-first)? Or are you designing everything from scratch?

Comment: Both, I know how I want my classes to be formed, as well as the database.  So, I tried starting with each (code-first, then generate database and then tried with database-first and have it generate the classes) and neither method matched.  I was more curious than anything because I do have a workaround, but it is just that, a workaround (in the elden times, we called that a hack).

Comment: Ok :-) well I can't really help with database-first, but anyway I suggest you do code-first, setup your model classes the way you want them to look, and then use EF migrations to create your database. That way you always end up with a DB matching your model.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.  The good thing is, I am to a point now to where I am able to tweak my model to get the tables/columns just right.  Thanks for the comments and suggestions.